# Разное поведение constexpr на разных платформах

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

Доброго времени суток. Есть класс, который включает в себя другой класс со статическими членами массивами. Я очень хочу сделать что бы у меня была возможность задать все статик значения этих членов в хедере а не в cpp части. Для этого я применил `constexpr` и эта схема нормально заработала на компиляторе от Microsoft. Однако на g++ под ARM на Debian этот код не компилируется:

> undefined reference to `Foo::Target::IP'

В обоих случаях используется С++14. Вопрос вот в чём. Почему один компилятор это принимает, а другой нет, т.е. в чём отличия работы с `constexpr` внутри у этих компиляторов? Это никак не стандартизовано? Что мне сделать, чтобы такая схема заработала?

```
class Foo {
public:
    static void GetIp(uint8_t* data) {
        memcpy(data, &Target::IP[0], 4);
    };
private:
    class Target {
    public:
        static constexpr uint8_t IP[4] = { 192,168,0,110 };
        static constexpr uint16_t Port = 3000;
    };
};
int main()
{
    uint8_t A[4];
    Foo::GetIp(A);
    printf("%u.%u.%u.%u", A[0], A[1], A[2], A[3]);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 0x14 - это 24 стандарт? вроде 23 будет. В любом случае, смотрите в версии компиляторов, может быть для arm он "немного старый".

Comment: @KoVadim я плохо понял что значит 24. Версия GCC 6.3. Обновить его будет очень тяжело.

Comment: а версия gcc в обеих случаях одна и таже? (0х в начале намекает на 16-ричную систему. но я не совсем верно перевел. 0х14 = 16+4 = 20. в любом случае, это была шутка)

Comment: В первом случае компилятор который по умолчанию идёт 17ой студии. С выбором стандарта языка 0х14. Как вообще можно было получить из 0x14 24 при смене системы счисления?)

Comment: я исправился с числами потом. gcc 6.3 для арм все хорошо компилирует https://godbolt.org/g/rGfae8

Comment: @KoVadim а это уже очень интересно. Спасибо большое за помощь, буду дальше разбираться.

Comment: @KoVadim Попробовал скомпилировать под ARM микроконтроллере, там компилятор GCC 7.2.1. Та же самая ошибка. Т.е. совсем другая машина с другой IDE компилирует под другой процессор без операционной системы. Компилирует относительно новой версией компилятора. И точно такая же ошибка.

Comment: А почему компилируете прямо на микроконтроллере? не лучше ли использовать кросс компиляцию? Компилятор на контроллере может быть весьма "специфичен".

Comment: @KoVadim опечатался. Не на микроконтроллере а под микроконтроллер. Т.е. кросскомпиляция. Попробовал и в Keil это сделать и в CLion.

Comment: Чтобы работал Ваш код, нужно использовать C++17 компилятор, в противном случае для статического объекта обязательно нужно иметь определение вне класса. Вне зависимости constexpr это или нет (если есть odr-use).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да чтоб заработало, все просто - добавить

```
constexpr uint8_t Foo::Target::IP[4];
```

Только и всего. См. https://ideone.com/ZMqPMn

Но вот что именно строго по стандарту, а что нет - тут я не скажу, не уверен. Понятно, что целочисленное поле и массив - разные вещи, но что именно стандарт разрешает, что нет, и что отдает на откуп реализации - не скажу...

Comment: Большое спасибо.